# Как поставить картинки в один ряд?

Tags: css

Не получается поставить картинки в один ряд с горизонтальной прокруткой.

Как только указываю в `img` ширину или высоту, изображения сдвигаются вниз.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/stopani/pen/odbyvj)

```css
#btablefix {
  background: #999;
  float: left;
  height: 48px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 220px;
}

#btablefix a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px 0 3px 3px;
  position: relative;
}

#btablefix img {
  height: 42px;
}

#btablefix span {
  background: #ef5350;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 17px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 2px;
  width: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div id="btablefix">

  <a href="#"><span>1</span><img src="https://b.radikal.ru/b35/1804/04/744729617079.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><span>1</span><img src="https://b.radikal.ru/b35/1804/04/744729617079.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><span>1</span><img src="https://b.radikal.ru/b35/1804/04/744729617079.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><span>1</span><img src="https://b.radikal.ru/b35/1804/04/744729617079.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><span>1</span><img src="https://b.radikal.ru/b35/1804/04/744729617079.jpg"></a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#btablefix {
  display: flex;
  background: #999;
  float: left;
  height: 58px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 220px;
}

#btablefix a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px 0 3px 3px;
  position: relative;
}

#btablefix img {
  width: 95px;
  height: 42px;
}

#btablefix span {
  background: #ef5350;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 17px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 2px;
  width: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div id="btablefix">

  <a href="#"><span>1</span><img src="https://b.radikal.ru/b35/1804/04/744729617079.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><span>1</span><img src="https://b.radikal.ru/b35/1804/04/744729617079.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><span>1</span><img src="https://b.radikal.ru/b35/1804/04/744729617079.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><span>1</span><img src="https://b.radikal.ru/b35/1804/04/744729617079.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#"><span>1</span><img src="https://b.radikal.ru/b35/1804/04/744729617079.jpg"></a>

</div>
```